# Determining if a linear transformation is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

$V = P_2(\mathbb{R}), W = P_3(\mathbb{R}), T : V \longrightarrow W$ such that $T(a + bx + cx^2) = a + bx + cx^2$ Determine whether or not the linear transformation is an isomorphism.

Workings:

Let B be a basis of $P_2\mathbb{R}$

Define

$T: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow W$

$\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} \mapsto a-bi$

Clearly $ker(T) = 0$

So T is injective

$\dim(P_2(\mathbb{R})) = \dim(P_3(\mathbb{R}))$

Then T is not surjective.

So T is not bijective and therefore T is not an ismorphism.

I'm not sure if I am correct. Any ehlp will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your argument but your conclusion is correct: $T$ is injective but not surjective thus $T$ is not an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$.  An easy way to show it's not surjective is to show that there is no $v\in V$ such that $T(v) = x^3$.

Comment: I just do it the way you said it then, just to be safe. Thanks.

Comment: $T$ is simply the *canonical injection* from $\mathbf R_2[x]$ to  $\mathbf R_3[x]$!